# Error (treedata): "names for 'data' must be supplied

Tags: tree, phylogeny

I'm trying to follow the code of [Use R!] Functional and Phylogenetic Ecology in R, with the exact same code and data files, but at one point there is an error that I can't solve.

> treedata(my.phylo, names(my.sample[1,my.sample[1,]>0]))

This should return the details of a subset (second argument) of a phylogenetic tree (first argument). However, appears:

> Error in treedata(my.phylo, names(my.sample[1, my.sample[1, ] >  : 
>     names for 'data' must be supplied

The names isn't already my argument? When running

> names(my.sample[1,my.sample[1,]>0])

is everything ok (returns the names I want), so the problem might not be here.  How to solve it?

Comment: First of all, welcome to SO. Second, please, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. We cannot help you without an example that can reproduce the problem. Specifically, here, what libraries do the functions come from? What is the data structure? I expect the problem to be in new argument organisation of the `treedata` function.

Answer (score -1):

You need to supply a vector of data containing species existing in a given community. You can try:
treedata(my.phylo, unlist(my.sample[1, my.sample[1,] > 0]), warnings = F)